# Rasterize gives weird image

Tags: raster, r

```
ro<-readShapeSpatial("roads")
ra<-readShapeSpatial("railways")
co<-readShapeSpatial("LIE_adm0")
u<-union(union(extent(ro),extent(ra)),extent(co))
rast<-raster(u,res=1)
r1<-rasterize(ro,rast)
r2<-rasterize(ra,rast)
r3<-rasterize(co,rast)
rMerge <- merge(r3, r2, r1, fun=sum, na.rm=T)
plot(rMerge)
```

question 1

I've heard readOGR is better than readShapeSpatial, can u tell me when and why is better?

question 2

Why the script doesn't return the map but it returns this thing below? I have already change the resolution from 1 to 10 and 100 and still the same.
.

[image: This is the image that returns]

Comment: Can you start de-bugging, i.e. plot r1, r2 and r3 separatly to see if any of them show the expected image. That will provide an insight to where is th problem. Edit your question with more info.

Comment: it also seems that the values you are plotting are coordinates; e.g. yellow toughly means 36.000 (looks like decimal degrees). Make sure you have rasterized the ShapeSpatial using a value, and not only with its coordinates.

Comment: About the more info, this is all i have if i plot it at the beginning before the rasterize, everything seems fine. Feel free to ask what else u need. I kind of get what u mean in ur comments but i can't fix them.

Comment: more info refers to the de-bugging as suggested above. Does plotting r1 give good results? etc.

If the problem is what I mention in the second comment (which seems to me that it is); you have to fix it, if you want to get something usefull out of it. That is make sure that this is the problem, and edit/open a new question narrowed down to how to fix it; or how to perform the process.

Comment: plot(r1) and plot(r2) gives the same image, the one i posted.plot(r3) gives a blank one. about the second comment and the decimal degrees what can i do?

Comment: yes, use readOGR, or with a simpler interface 'shapefile' in raster, because then you get the coordinate reference system of the data. A resolution of 1 is clearly not useful. What you are seeing is a map of one raster cell that has a single value (36). So do change the resolution to 100 cells and the results really should be different.

Answer (score 1):

A resolution of 1 is clearly not useful in this case. What you are seeing is a map of one raster cell (~ 9.5 - 10.5; 46.3 - 47.3) that has a single value (36). Had you provided more information, e.g. show(rMerge), it would have been very easy to spot.

Do change the resolution and the results really should be different. But the resolution should be higher, that is, a smaller number, that is, not 10 or 100, but 1/10 or 1/100 (such that you get more cells!). Or use the raster(u, nrow=10, ncol=10)

```
u <- union(union(extent(ro),extent(ra)),extent(co))
rast <- raster(u, ncol=10, nrow=10)
r1 <- rasterize(ro, rast)
r2 <- rasterize(ra, rast)
r3 <- rasterize(co, rast)
rMerge <- merge(r3, r2, r1, fun=sum, na.rm=T)
plot(rMerge)
```

yes, use readOGR, or with a simpler interface 'shapefile' in raster, because then you get the coordinate reference system of the data as well; readShapeSpatial does not return that.

Comment: i didn't thought of a fractional resolution indeed. :D  Now, could u be more specific about when is readOGR more suitable and when readShapeSpatial and the reason behind it? Also, can u provide a route that will run the above code faster? because with so much high resolutions it takes 30 min to run it.